# Is there any text data set with both paragraph and document-level labels available?

Tags: data-request, text

I am looking for a text data-set. I need this data-set for a set of experiments which compares effectiveness of a set of algorithms working in paragraph-level with the same algorithms working in document-level. For this reason, I want a data-set which has both paragraph-level and document-level labels. It's ok if only a subset of items in each level has labels. I found a lot of paper, which worked on a text processing on both paragraph-level and document-level data-sets but none of their data-sets is publicly available.

Edit: I want to do a set of experiments at the paragraph-level and see if the result is better than learning the same concept at the document-level. As long as labels are binary, it's not important what is labels.

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you clarify what "at the document level" means? so you want a bunch of content in marked up, <p>, but they're all going to be in an html document (ideally)....so i'm just confused. sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I think The [British National Corpus](http://ota.ox.ac.uk/desc/2554) could do the job. It's a large and free corpus labeled at [document, sentence and paragraph level](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/docs/URG/cdifbase.html#cdifcomp) (but also word level, so you'll have a lot of useless xml tags to clean).

It's a big file. The best, for testing, is probably to download the [Baby edition](http://ota.ox.ac.uk/desc/2553) (less than 200 Mb once uncompressed). As you can see in the sample   below, the documents are labelled `<wtext>`, the paragraphs `<p>`, the sentences `<s>`(and the words `<w>`, of course).

```
<bncDoc xml:id="A9Y">
    <teiHeader>
     ...
    </teiHeader>
    <wtext type="NEWS">
        <div level="1" n="13-DEC-89 edition, page 39">
            <head>
                <s n="1">
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="obituary" pos="SUBST">Obituary</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">: </c>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="dr" pos="SUBST">Dr </w>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="jack" pos="SUBST">Jack </w>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="kahn" pos="SUBST">Kahn</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
                </s>
            </head>
            <p>
                <s n="1">
                    <w c5="CRD" hw="one" pos="ADJ">ONE </w>
                    <w c5="PRF" hw="of" pos="PREP">of </w>
                    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
                    <w c5="NN2" hw="luminary" pos="SUBST">luminaries </w>
                    <w c5="PRF" hw="of" pos="PREP">of </w>
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="child" pos="SUBST">child </w>
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="psychiatry" pos="SUBST">psychiatry </w>
                    <w c5="VHZ" hw="have" pos="VERB">has </w>
                    <w c5="VVN" hw="leave" pos="VERB">left </w>
                    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">us</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
                </s>
                <s n="2">
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="jack" pos="SUBST">Jack </w>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="kahn" pos="SUBST">Kahn </w>
                    <w c5="VVD" hw="graduate" pos="VERB">graduated </w>
                    <w c5="PRP" hw="with" pos="PREP">with </w>
                    <w c5="NN2" hw="honour" pos="SUBST">honours </w>
                    <w c5="PRP" hw="at" pos="PREP">at </w>
                    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="university" pos="SUBST">University </w>
                    <w c5="PRF" hw="of" pos="PREP">of </w>
                    <w c5="NP0" hw="leeds" pos="SUBST">Leeds </w>
                    <w c5="PRP" hw="in" pos="PREP">in </w>
                    <w c5="CRD" hw="1928" pos="ADJ">1928 </w>
                    <w c5="CJC" hw="and" pos="CONJ">and </w>
                    <w c5="VVN-VVD" hw="achieve" pos="VERB">achieved </w>
                    <w c5="AT0" hw="an" pos="ART">an </w>
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="md" pos="SUBST">MD </w>
                    <w c5="PRP" hw="from" pos="PREP">from </w>
                    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
                    <w c5="DT0" hw="same" pos="ADJ">same </w>
                    <w c5="NN1" hw="university" pos="SUBST">university</w>
                    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
                </s>
            </p>
        </div>
    </wtext>
</bncDoc>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you. It's a huge corpus. And I don't understand it's structure. Would you please tell me for example that what I can use for text-level labels and what for paragraph-level labels?

Comment: It's good if the labels are not the same in paragraph-level with labels in document-level.

Comment: @user85361 I'v edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you. It's very good. What is the labels for paragraphs? Is there any kind of labels for paragraphs or sentences?

Comment: What is not clear in the answer ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know XML and I am new to NLP. I don't see any labels for paragraphs. Please make it more explicit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Text8 corpus of Wikipedia [text](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/textdata.html) as mentioned in the research paper [Learning Image Embeddings using Convolutional Neural Networks for Improved Multi-Modal Semantics](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~dk427/papers/emnlp2014.pdf). I recently worked on a research work and have the dataset you are looking. However you need to wait till 30th March 2017 to have hands on this dataset.

Comment: Hi, Now, Could you please let have the dataset?Thank you very much.